# Can't create function in phpMyAdmin in SQL window on 000webhost.com

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a very simple test function.
It works here in [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d60bb/2/0)

```
CREATE FUNCTION myTestFunc(inNum int) returns int
begin
  declare returnVal int;
  SET returnVal = 88;
  return returnVal;
end//
```

But when I am on the 000webhost.com, and go to phpMyAdmin and then try it in the SQL window
I keep getting this error:

MySQL said: Documentation
 #1558 - Column count of mysql.proc is wrong. Expected 20, found 16. Created with MySQL 50090, now running 50158. Please use mysql_upgrade to fix this error.

Comment: your host has screwed up the mysql install and are running with outdated mysql.* schema

Comment: well that isn't very good news!

Comment: I tried sending a ticket and see if they can resolve it.

Comment: boo! this is what they replied with: Unfortunately we cannot change the default server configuration as it would affect all other users hosted on this server. Current server configuration enables maximum security and optimized performance for the server and users, thus it cannot be changed.

On the other hand, this feature/function can be enabled on our premium servers. Feel free to recheck and upgrade Your account

Comment: so basically because it is a free account, they won't bother look into it :(

Comment: Yep, as usual. "You're getting what you paid for".